# Why do I have a run time error 1004: Object not defined when document has 10,000 rows or greater?

Tags: excel, object, runtime-error, vba

I am opening a excel document from a file dialog window using vba.  When the document selected through the file dialog has 999 rows it works without error.  when the document has 10000 rows I receive a runtime error 1004 object defined error.  This error began to occur as I changed the procedure to copy a column instead of the whole document.  This exact line works on a doc with 9999 rows but erros on the same doc when 1 more row added.

```
 wb.Sheets("Sheet1").range("E1", "E1" & lastRowC) = wb1.Sheets(Sheet2").range(EEid.Address, EEid.Address & lastRowC).value
```

Comment: `"E1" & lastRowC` should be `"E" & lastRowC`

Comment: And change `.range(EEid.Address, EEid.Address & lastRowC).` to `.Range(EEid,wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(EEid.Row + lastRowC,EEid.Column)).`

Comment: And `= wb1.Sheets(Sheet2")` should be `= wb1.Sheets("Sheet2")` but I suspect that is just a type here on SO.

Comment: Basically the `&` is not adding the 1 and the `lastRowC` number together.  It is concatenating them so `9999` become `E19999` not `E10000`  And if the number are large enough then it goes off the sheet.

Comment: Thank you.  That works great, but it is adding 99999 rows with #N/A after the expected range is copied & pasted.  Why would this occur?

Comment: That is because your paste area is greater than you data area.  I edited my comment a few times make sure you are using the latest above.  It should make the ranges the same size.

Comment: Will the paste range " wb.Sheets("Sheet1").range("E1", "E1" & lastRowC)" require an update as well?

Comment: Current working code displaying extra #N/A is listed below. wb.Sheets("Carrier").range("E1", "E1" & lastRowC) = wb1.Sheets("Page1_1").range(EEid, wb1.Sheets("Page1_1").Cells(EEid.Row + lastRowC, EEid.Column)).value

Comment: This makes the procedure run for a very long time.  I am unsure what my error is when setting my paste range.